# Тег <input> атрибут type тип text

Tags: php, html, html5

Меняется содержание текстового поля №1 и тут же (без сохранения) должно поменяться содержание текстового поля №2. 
Это возможно? Если возможно, покажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например можно подписаться на ввод данных в в одно поле, и ставить это значение в другое.

`element.addEventListener` - добавляет событие к элементу.

```js
var inp1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var inp2 = document.getElementById('input2');

input1.addEventListener('input', function (value) {
    inp2.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function repeatText() {
   document.getElementById("text2").value = document.getElementById("text1").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="repeatText()">
<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="text2">
```

Comment: задержку видишь в своем скрипте при вводе значения?)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев пока ничего не вижу, потому что никак не соображу, как эту функцию подпихнуть, когда у меня всё на php. Я просто совсем ещё зеленая. До меня долго может доходить. )

Comment: @Юленька php это сервер, js/html/css - это клиент. Различайте эти две вещи. То что вы спрашиваете, сделано на `javascript`.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев в смысле "php это сервер"? php разве не  скриптовый язык. Да, javascript я различаю. Ладно... в любом случае спасибо за идею. Просто пока у меня мало знаний. Может получится что попроще изобрести.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев а,я кажется поняла о чем вы.)

Comment: @Юленька php это `СЕРВЕРНЫЙ ЯЗЫК`. Исполняется (интерпритируется) он на сервере, и только там. На клиенте исполняется все что связано с отображением, подгрузкой данных с СЕРВЕРА, визуализация и тому подобное. Почитайте документации или посмотрите видео-уроки. Быстрее научитесь и поймете. PS. большими буквами указал на важное, это я не кричу :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев О! Я разобралась. Так, а я могу туда условие дописать? То есть, если я в "text1" ввожу число больше 35, то в "text2" должно появляться, например cat, если в "text1" число меньше 35, то в "text2" будет выводиться dog? Данный метод это позволяет?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я поняла про сервер.) Ничего я научусь. Я читаю и вот на интенсив буду записываться, когда набор откроют. Извините, что до меня долго доходит. )

Comment: @Юленька и мой и этот метод позволяют, только этот работает с задержкой. В мой так же можете написать условие `if (this.value == 'чемуторавно') { /*что делать*/ }`

Comment: @Юленька ничего, обращайтесь)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Спасибо вам огромнейшее! Вы меня так выручили!!! =))) Всё теперь как надо.

Comment: @Юленька странно, что вы правильным отметили менее правильный ответ))) Ну да ладно)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ой, да я просто отметила там, где мы и разговаривали. Поправила. )